# Symfony Security component register form ChoiceType field insert into bdd as an array(for the roles a user as)

Tags: symfony

When i register with my form(1) the roles the user select isn't entered in the bdd instead it enter just [] i couldn't get it enter either ROLE_USER or ROLE_ADVERTISER or both in array in the bdd, roles is a longtext in,
[image: (1)]

[image: (2)]

Here is my Form builder:

```
class RegistrationFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('agreeTerms', CheckboxType::class, [
                'mapped' => false,
                'constraints' => [
                    new IsTrue([
                        'message' => 'You should agree to our terms.',
                    ]),
                ],
            ])
            ->add('plainPassword', PasswordType::class, [
                // instead of being set onto the object directly,
                // this is read and encoded in the controller
                'mapped' => false,
                'constraints' => [
                    new NotBlank([
                        'message' => 'Please enter a password',
                    ]),
                    new Length([
                        'min' => 6,
                        'minMessage' => 'Your password should be at least {{ limit }} characters',
                        // max length allowed by Symfony for security reasons
                        'max' => 4096,
                    ]),
                ],
            ])
            ->add('roles', ChoiceType::class, [
                'required' => true,
                'multiple' => false,
                'expanded' => false,
                'choices' => [
                    'ROLE_USER' => 'ROLE_USER',
                    'ROLE_ADVERTISER' => 'ROLE_ADVERTISER',
                ],
            ]);
        $builder->get('roles')
            ->addModelTransformer(new CallbackTransformer(
                function ($rolesArray) {
                    // transform the array to a string
                    return count($rolesArray)? $rolesArray[0]: null;
                },
                function ($rolesString) {
                    // transform the string back to an array
                    return [$rolesString];
                }
        ));
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => User::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please add the column definition for `User::roles`

Comment: adder @ArleighHix

Comment: What happens without calling `->addModelTransformer(...)`?